# Can we automate functional testcases using WATIR for IE in headless mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, automation, watir-webdriver

I want to automate a few work flows of my web application using watir-webdriver.
I am using Ubuntu. I want to automate all the workflows on IE. As i am using ubuntu as my platform, need to run it in headless mode.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You will have to provide more information. How to you plan to run Internet Explorer on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a VM or separate machine to test IE.  If you attempt to run IE test in Ubuntu you will most likely not be able to find the IEDriverServer needed.  You may be able to use Wine or some other solution, but I don't know of any support for this.